# how to get unique data from database using eloquent model (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-models

here is my code -

```
$list = Plot::active()
             ->whereNotNull('user_id')
             ->distinct('user_id')
             ->with('user')
             ->paginate(10);
```

but here "distinct('user_id')" not working. I want only unique user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in this way -

```
$list = User::has('plots')->whereHas('plots', function ($query) {
            $query->active();
        })->with('plots')->paginate(10);
```

user - hasMany plots (one to many relationship)

plot - belongsTo user (many to one relationship)